# navigation bar with drop down navigation is not taking full browser width

Tags: html, css, list, menu, navigation

Hi I am creating a drop down menu using unordered list and I want to make the navigation width full without affecting the dropdown menu.

When I try to do this with parent `div(.menu)` then the overflow problem occurs. I want the menu to take up the entire width in the browser with text of navigation center align. Thanks in advance.

```css
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li {
  width: 220px;
  height: 35px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 35px;
}
.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
.menu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 220px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Booking</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">History</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub3</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Wrestlers</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

[image: Image attached]

Comment: Ul { width:100%; background-color:red;}?

Comment: Your css is not valid. First remove excess quotes from styles of `.menu ul li` after `height` property.

Comment: can you edit the above code and make it right??

Comment: What are you wanting to be full width - the top level menu or the drop down sub menus?

Comment: top level menu. its on the left side. i want it to take the full width and the menu text to be center aligned and the sub menu should appear the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this css. you set the width of each of the menu options to 220px instead of 20%.

```
.menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding-left:0px;
}
.menu ul li {
  width: 20%;
  height: 35px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 35px;
}
.menu ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 display: block;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
.menu ul ul ul {
  margin-left:100%;
  top: 0px;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul {

 width:100%;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul> li {
 display: block;
 width:100%;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul> li > ul {
  width:100%;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul> li > ul > li{
 display: block;
 width:100%;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: this makes the navigation bar full but affecting the drop down menu and sub menu

Comment: @saad-qureshi i have added extra css take a look

Comment: @saad-qureshi Give that a try i think i fixed it